# Display ALL when all the values are selected

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have dropdown parameter with multi-values allowed.
In my report header I want to show all the dropdown values that were checked by the user to run the report. But since there could be a couple of hundred values I want to show 'ALL' when all the values are selected instead of listing them one by one.
How can I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: With the greatest difficulty. Seriously, for parameters which offer more than a couple of dozen values, it normally makes more sense to use a LIKE than an IN.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could feed the results into a subreport which would count the total # of values available vs selected.  If they are equal, then it would return "All".

Comment: +1 - That was the only thing I could come up with either.  It seems Crystal Report (or at least the versions I've played with) don't have a way of calculating the maximum number of options.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a static list, you can do something like this :

```
If UBound({?MyParameter}) = @ValueCount Then 'All' Else Join({?MyParameter}, ', ')
```

where @ValueCount is the number of possible values for the parameter.

If the number of possible parameters is varying between executions, then PowerUser's subreport method is one option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you read the list of parameter values from the database, you can then use a query to get the number of options.

Edit the parameter, set "List of Values" = Dynamic

Add a Command in the Database Expert to get your option count, something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT option) optCount FROM optTable
```

Then, building on CodeByMoonlight's suggestion, use a formula:

```
If UBound({?MyParameter}) = {Command.optCount} THEN "ALL"
ELSE Join({?MyParameter}, ', ')
```